# Resizing images using createjs / easeljs

Tags: javascript, canvas, image-resizing, createjs, easeljs

I'd like to dynamically downsize some images on my canvas using createjs, and then store the smaller images to be displayed when zooming out of the canvas for performance reasons. Right now, I'm using the following code:

```
var bitmap = createjs.Bitmap('somefile.png');
// wait for bitmap to load (using preload.js etc.)

var oc = document.createElement('canvas');
var octx = oc.getContext('2d');
oc.width = bitmap.image.width*0.5;
oc.height = bitmap.image.height*0.5;
octx.drawImage(bitmap.image, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

var dataUrl = oc.toDataURL('image/png'); // very expensive
var smallBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(dataUrl);
```

This works, but:

1. The `toDataURL` operation is very expensive when converting to `image/png` and too slow to use in practice (and I can't convert to the faster `image/jpeg` due to the insufficient quality of the output for all settings I tried)
2. Surely there must be a way to downsize the image without having to resort to separate canvas code, and then do a conversion manually to draw onto the createjs Bitmap object??

I've also tried:

```
octx.drawImage(bitmap.image, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
var smallBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(oc);
```

But although very fast, this doesn't seem to actually work (and in any case I'm having to create a separate `canvas` element every time to facilitate this.)

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can use `drawImage` to draw a downsampled version of the bitmap into a createjs Bitmap instance directly without having to go via a separate canvas object or do a conversion to string?

If I understand correctly, internally this is how the createjs `cache` property works (i.e. uses `drawImage` internally to write into the DisplayObject) but I'm unable to figure out how use it myself.

Comment: Wait, why? why not just use [`contex.drawImage(0,0,desiredwidth,desiredheight)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and then use [`canvas.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get the resized image? This is something canvas can already do with its own APIs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's what I've basically done above? I'm not sure where the context you refer to comes from, but that's what `octx` is above. Also, as mentioned, I'm trying to avoid the very expensive call to `canvas.toDataURL()`. Also happy to use native canvas routines, but would then need some way to wrap the resultant image into a createjs Bitmap object (as I'm using createjs for managing everything else).

Comment: I don't understand the "too slow" part though, what are you *actually* doing that requires you run this so often that its performance is an issue?

Comment: All I can say is that if I replace 'image/png' with 'image/jpeg' the browser remains responsive throughout (Chrome + Safari) – with the png encoding there is noticeable stuttering on the page, presumably as the main thread is blocked by this operation. In answer to your question about volumes – I have a large number of high-quality retina ready assets which I'd like to resize in real-time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, toDataURL() actually encodes the image into a specific format – therefore my question is whether it's possible to transfer the contents of a canvas to a createjs Bitmap object directly without this seemingly redundant encoding step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tagged this post with `createjs` and `easeljs`, but your examples show plain Canvas context usage for scaling.

You can use the `scale` parameter on `Bitmap.cache()` to get the result you want, then reuse the `cacheCanvas` as necessary.

```
// This will create a half-size cache (50%)
// But scale it back up for you when it displays on the stage
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
bmp.cache(0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0.5);

// Pull out the generated cache and use it in a new Bitmap
// This will display at the new scaled size.
var bmp2 = new createjs.Bitmap(bmp.cacheCanvas);

// Un-cache the first one to reset it if you want
bmp.uncache();
```

Here is a fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ofdsyn7g/

Note that caching just uses another canvas with a drawImage to scale it down. I definitely would stay away from toDataURL, as it not performant at all.

Comment: That's amazing Lanny – thanks so much for the help! Wasn't sure how to do the resize with createjs directly, thus the plain canvas context usage, but now I don't need to now that you've shown how to do with createjs directly. Had a feeling I might be able to use the cache in some way, but it wasn't particularly clear from the documentation.

Comment: Isn't setting `bmp`'s `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties both to `0.5` after caching at `0.5` resolution a better idea than creating a new bitmap from the cache canvas?

Comment: Good point Tiago! Though you'd then have to discard the downsized cached image to get back to the original full sized one. Also, would imagine the image downsizing is much more expensive than the creation of a new Bitmap.

Comment: @KenChatfield Indeed, but I really doubt about the expensiveness of the `scale` properties. Creating a whole new bitmap object sounds a lot more expensive to me.

Comment: Caching does have a cost, but its just a single extra `drawImage`. It will save processing and memory down the road, and can be a good technique when used right.