# Dealing with large images in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a 15000x15000 px vector image that I want to use as the background for a canvas project. I need to be able to cut a piece of the image and draw it as a background quickly and often (within `requestAnimationFrame`).

To draw the needed sector of the image I'm using...

```
const xOffset = (pos.x - (canvas.width / 2)) + config.bgOffset + config.arenaRadius;
const yOffset = (pos.y - (canvas.height / 2)) + config.bgOffset + config.arenaRadius;
c.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

To calculate the area of the background needed and draw the image. This all works fine but redrawing is slow and the first draw is even slower.

Loading this huge image seems ridiculous and performance is sluggish. How can I reduce file size or otherwise improve performance?

**EDIT:** There is no reasonable solution to drawing such a large image at its full size. Because the background is a repeating pattern, my current solution is to take one pattern "cell" and draw it multiple times.

Comment: How large is your canvas? Also, vector image as in SVG?

Comment: @MátéSafranka The canvas scales to screen size. The native size that I'm designing at is 1920x1080 (1920x974 for the actual window). I made the background in Affinity Designer so I could export as an SVG.

Comment: I'm venturing a little outside my confidence zone, but here's my two cents. Drawing a slice of a bitmap shouldn't be an especially CPU-intensive operation, since it's basically just copying a bunch of bytes from one buffer to another. The only source of slowdown I can imagine there is the amount of bytes to copy, i.e. the size of the *target* canvas. However -- and this is where my confidence falters -- drawing from an SVG might be a whole other thing, since in that case  the source isn't a bitmap, meaning there's a whole lot of additional calculations.

Comment: So, besides using a smaller canvas, my only guess would be to use a bitmap instead of an SVG as a source. However, at 15k by 15k pixels, that would probably eat up an inordinate amount of memory.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I'll mess around with it a bit more to see how slow it is as I progress with the project. The image file size is 9.23MB... I guess that just raised some red flags. As for your last point, the image was designed with a vector program but can be exported as a PNG (which is what I was using). In fact, when I first tried, drawing an SVG didn't even work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15000px x 15000px is indeed big.

The GPU would have to store it as raw RGB data in its memory (I don't remember the Maths exactly but I think it's something like width x height x 3 bytes, i.e 675MB in your case, which is more than most common GPUs can handle).
Add to that all the other graphics you might have, and your GPU will be forced to drop your big image and to grab it again every frame.

In order to avoid that, you'd probably be better to split your big image into multiple smaller ones, and to call multiple times `drawImage` per frame. This way, in worst case, the GPU will only have to fetch the part needed, and in best case, it will already have it in its memory.

Here is a rough proof of concept, which will split a 5000*5000px svg image in tiles of 250*250px.  Of course, you will have to adapt it for your needs, but it might give you an idea.

```js
console.log('generating image...');
var bigImg = new Image();
bigImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(generateBigImage(5000, 5000));
bigImg.onload = init;

function splitBigImage(img, maxSize) {
  if (!maxSize || typeof maxSize !== 'number') maxSize = 500;

  var iw = img.naturalWidth,
    ih = img.naturalHeight,
    tw = Math.min(maxSize, iw),
    th = Math.min(maxSize, ih),
    tileCols = Math.ceil(iw / tw), // how many columns we'll have
    tileRows = Math.ceil(ih / th), // how many rows we'll have
    tiles = [],
    r, c, canvas;

  // draw every part of our image once on different canvases
  for (r = 0; r < tileRows; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < tileCols; c++) {
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      // add a 1px margin all around for antialiasing when drawing at non integer
      canvas.width = tw + 2;
      canvas.height = th + 2;
      canvas.getContext('2d')
        .drawImage(img,
          (c * tw | 0) - 1, // compensate the 1px margin
          (r * tw | 0) - 1,
          iw, ih, 0, 0, iw, ih);
      tiles.push(canvas);
    }
  }

  return {
    width: iw,
    height: ih,
    // the drawing function, takes the output context and x,y positions
    draw: function drawBackground(ctx, x, y) {
      var cw = ctx.canvas.width,
        ch = ctx.canvas.height;
      // get our visible rectangle as rows and columns indexes
      var firstRowIndex = Math.max(Math.floor((y - th) / th), 0),
        lastRowIndex = Math.min(Math.ceil((ch + y) / th), tileRows),
        firstColIndex = Math.max(Math.floor((x - tw) / tw), 0),
        lastColIndex = Math.min(Math.ceil((cw + x) / tw), tileCols);

      var col, row;
      // loop through visible tiles and draw them
      for (row = firstRowIndex; row < lastRowIndex; row++) {
        for (col = firstColIndex; col < lastColIndex; col++) {
          ctx.drawImage(
            tiles[row * tileCols + col], // which part
            col * tw - x - 1, // x position
            row * th - y - 1 // y position
          );
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

function init() {
  console.log('image loaded');

  var bg = splitBigImage(bigImg, 250); // image_source, maxSize
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var dx = 1,
    dy = 1,
    x = 150,
    y = 150;
  anim();
  setInterval(changeDirection, 2000);

  function anim() {
    // just to make the background position move...
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if (x < 0) {
      dx *= -1;
      x = 1;
    }
    if (x > bg.width - ctx.canvas.width) {
      dx *= -1;
      x = bg.width - ctx.canvas.width - 1;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      dy *= -1;
      y = 1;
    }
    if (y > bg.height - ctx.canvas.height) {
      dy *= -1;
      y = bg.height - ctx.canvas.height - 1;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    if(chck.checked) {
      // that's how you call it
      bg.draw(ctx, x, y);
    }
    else {
      ctx.drawImage(bigImg, -x, -y);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }

  function changeDirection() {
    dx = (Math.random()) * 5 * Math.sign(dx);
    dy = (Math.random()) * 5 * Math.sign(dy);
  }

  setTimeout(function() { console.clear(); }, 1000);
}
// produces a width * height pseudo-random svg image
function generateBigImage(width, height) {
  var str = '<svg width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">',
    x, y;
  for (y = 0; y < height / 20; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < width / 20; x++)
      str += '<circle ' +
      'cx="' + ((x * 20) + 10) + '" ' +
      'cy="' + ((y * 20) + 10) + '" ' +
      'r="15" ' +
      'fill="hsl(' + (width * height / ((y * x) + width)) + 'deg, ' + (((width + height) / (x + y)) + 35) + '%, 50%)" ' +
      '/>';
  str += '</svg>';
  return new Blob([str], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml'
  });
}
```

```html
<label>draw split <input type="checkbox" id="chck" checked></label>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

And actually, in your specific case, I would personally even store split images on the server (be it in svg since it should take less bandwidth), and generate the tiles from different sources. But I'll let it for the reader as an exercise.

Comment: I actually ended up using a method somewhat similar to this... since my background is a repeating pattern I took one pattern "cell" and draw it multiple times. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using **EaselJS** to render multiple/large objects to HTML canvas. This library supports vector caching, webgl and much more.

Here is an example of **caching** multiple vector objects into bitmaps (click the checkbox for comparison):
https://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/cache

You should be able to treat your background vector the same way. Simply cache the object and let the software handle all the heavy lifting.

Comment: That demo was impressive. I'll look into this, thanks!

Comment: None of these demo demonstrate how it improves drawing big images. OP's case is an already rasterized image of 15000 * 15000 px. EaselJS caching strategy is to avoid calling multiple times the same Path methods, by generating a rasterized version of it. That won't help OP.

Comment: @kaiido, here is a great example of using 'cacheCanvas' after the vector has been turned into a bitmap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991855/2510368. Theoretically, you can cache a large vector into a large bitmap, then cache a small bitmap from that canvas object.

Comment: @Kaiido, I do understand. Assuming this 15000x15000 image (vector or bitmap) is static, you can 'cacheCanvas' the image to something like 800x600 and redraw it at a much smaller dimension.

Comment: @doppler but the image needs to be displayed at its real scale. Anyway, I'll stop arguing and stick to my first comment which states that this answer doesn't target the question being asked ("Dealing with large images in HTML5 canvas").

Comment: EaselJS does not solve the original image issue, but I did end up using it for its other benefits so thank you for the recommendation.